# How to coustomize the preview of camera on surface view?

Tags: android

how to change to camera preview like this in Android Camera..
(See Attached Image)
in first preview is simple preview of camera.
i want my camera preview like second preview.

[image]

Any Help,Code or Tutorial for this.

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0):

As Camera preview is nothing but an surfaceView, you can place 4 such views in a layout to get a look as in the second screen.